# How to do clean and build in eclipse using Ant

Tags: eclipse, ant, build

Is it possible to do clean and build a project using ant in eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition of the answer from Wing C. Chen, if you are looking for a way to interact with eclipse from ant, this may help you: [Ant tasks provided by the platform](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ant_eclipse_tasks.htm).

There you can find some task to interact with the platform, like one to cause eclipse to do an incremental build.

Comment: Thanks Andrea. Syntax is  <eclipse.incrementalBuild project="ProjName" kind="clean"/>

Answer (score 3):

You can execute any ant "**target**" in eclipse. Open then the **build.xml**, click the "**outline**" view, and you will see the targets listed in green bubble from. Right-click the one that you would like to run, select "**run as**", and then "**ant build**". You should be able to run the target up already.

Comment: Window -> Show View -> Outline